# Parse string with Python and pull numbers for simple math

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am running "Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2" on Ubuntu.

I have a line as follows from serial:

```
line="[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=31987895     BarC=1.15     sensorVal=226 -"
```

and wish to parse this. I need to extract 1.15 and 226 as numbers so I can do math with those numbers.

I have used the following python code:

```
pressure=line.split()[3].split("=")[1:2]
print(pressure)
```

This prints this:

```
['1.15']
```

How do I get rid of the  `' '` (apostrophes) and the  `[  ]`  and turn this into something I can do simple math with. A floating number will be fine.

**Here is more output:**

```
Listening at 868 Mhz...
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48743987     BarC=1.19     sensorVal=229 - ACK sent. Sending packet to node 99 - waiting for ACK...nothing...
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48745052     BarC=1.19     sensorVal=229
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48527151     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230 - ACK sent. Sending packet to node 99 - waiting for ACK...nothing...
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48528216     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48529276     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230 - ACK sent. Sending packet to node 99 - waiting for ACK...nothing...
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48530341     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48531402     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230 - ACK sent. Sending packet to node 99 - waiting for ACK...nothing...
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48532467     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48533528     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230 - ACK sent. Sending packet to node 99 - waiting for ACK...nothing...
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48534594     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48535655     BarC=1.20     sensorVal=230 - ACK sent. Sending packet to node 99 - waiting for ACK...nothing...
[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=48536720     BarC=1.20     sen**
```

Comment: `pressure=float(line.split()[3].split("=")[1:2][0])`. Currently you have a single-element list containing a string. So take the 0th index and cast the string to `float`

Comment: @roganjosh I tried that in the code and the error is "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Tested it locally and it worked for your example, but I imagined that it wouldn't be applicable in a broader case. The answer by Ajax is more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring the usage of regular expressions, I would like to help you understand why you have a problem in the first place.

It appears that you have concocted a long sequence of method calls that give you something very close to what you want without paying attention to the return values. Let's break it down:

`line` is a string. `line.split()` returns a list of the space-separated string elements of in `line`. `[3]` gets the fourth element of the list, which is again a string. `.split('=')` breaks it into a list again. `[1:2]` extracts the second element as a *sublist*. You can get the first element of the list by indexing `pressure[0]`. A much easier way would be to extract the index as `[1]` instead of `[1:2]`, which would return the second element as a string instead of a list.

In general, it is a good idea to process each of these steps in a separate line. Error checking is another reason to do this. Lines like `Listening at 868 Mhz...` do not have an `=` in the fourth element (`Mhz...`). There may also be lines that don't even have four elements. Either one will cause an `IndexError`.

To parse the a float number, just wrap the final string result in a call to `float`.

Here is a better way to extract the number string using the same calls:

```
elems = line.split()
if len(elems) > 3:
    items = elems[3].split('=')
    if len(items) > 1:
        pressure = float(items[1])
```

This should show you why regex is a cleaner option for something like this.

Comment: You are wrong and a bit cock sure of yourself there. I tried that hours ago. For completeness I just tried again. The error I just got is the same as hours ago. `IndexError: list index out of range`. Interestingly it works in the >>> env but not in the script.

Comment: @Kes. That is in the first line. Will fix.

Comment: @Kes. Updated for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: Tried that. Ran a few times ok. Then I reformatted for use here. It fell over. Put it all back and fell over again. Going to bed. It's 430am here. Thanks for your help. Here is the error `connected to: /dev/ttyUSB0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial-to-mqtt.py", line 55, in <module>
    items = elems[4].split('=')
IndexError: list index out of range` Ln 55 is `items = elems[4].split('=')` Error may be elsewhere.

Comment: @Kes, when you switched to using `elems[4]`, did you update the `if` above it to read `if len(elems) > 4:`? The whole point of that `if` is to make sure you don't get that error....

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.findall` for a broader solution:

```
import re
s = 'line="[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=31987895     BarC=1.15     sensorVal=226 -"'
a, b = map(float, re.findall('\d+\.*\d+', s))[-2:]
print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
(1.15, 226.0)
```

Edit: Assuming your output is `[[227.0, 99.0] [1.17, 227.0] [228.0, 99.0] [1.17, 227.0] [228.0, 99.0]]`, can try this:

```
s = [[227.0, 99.0] [1.17, 227.0] [228.0, 99.0] [1.17, 227.0] [228.0, 99.0]]
final_data = [i[0] for i in s[:2]]
```

Comment: Thanks. It comes back "ValueError: could not convert string to float: ..."

Comment: @Kes that is odd, as it works for me perfectly. Is there more of the string that you have not posted?

Comment: I have added more output above, Including  starting of Serial above.

Comment: I tried again and actually got an error. Here it is `connected to: /dev/ttyUSB0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial-to-mqtt.py", line 47, in <module>
    a, b = map(float, re.findall('[\d\.]+', line))[-2:]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .
'

Comment: @Kes Please see my recent edit, as I changed the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks @Axel1234. It works though when I attempt to re-assign variables it comes back with `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Comment: @Kes in that case, you will have assign the values to a list, rather than unpack: `values = map(float, re.findall('\d+\.*\d+', s))[-2:]`

Comment: Thanks @Axel1234. I'm able to print `values`. How do I assign the first value to variable a and the second to variable b? (Rather than seeing [227.0, 99.0] in reverse order. Variables appear in alternating order ...`[227.0, 99.0]
[1.17, 227.0]
[228.0, 99.0]
[1.17, 227.0]
[228.0, 99.0]`

Comment: @Kes for the first and second variables, are you referring to `[227.0, 99.0] [1.17, 227.0] `?

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234. There is some drift in the values there. Each of those numbers should be parsed as a different variable. The only two I am interested in are 227 and 1.17.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
import re
line="[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=31987895     BarC=1.15     sensorVal=226 -"
print [float(_) for _ in (re.findall(pattern="=([\d\.]+)", string=line)[-2:])]
```

**output:**
[1.15, 226.0]

to get values in variables:

```
(a, b) = (float(_) for _ in (re.findall(pattern="=([\d\.]+)", string=line)[-2:]))
print a, b
```

**output:**
1.15 226.0

Comment: Thanks. That works. How do I get both values out to variables?

Comment: @Kes I have updated answer with how to fetch values in variables.

Comment: Thanks. After implementing second part it just hangs. Dosen't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two non-regex solutions.

The first simply uses the (apparent) fact that the data is presented using fixed width fields. In each data line the value for `BarC` starts at offset 44 and ends before position 53. Similarly `sensorVal` starts at offset 63 and ends before 67. You can use string slicing to extract the values like this:

```
line = "[99]  nodeId=99    uptime=31987895     BarC=1.15     sensorVal=226 -"

if `BarC` in line:        # test whether this is a data line
    pressure = float(line[44:53])
    sensor_val = int(line[63:67])
```

Another way is to use `split()` to break the line up, then look for substrings containing an `=`. Then split the substrings into key/value pairs and create a dictionary:

```
data = {}
if 'BarC' in line:
    for s in line.split():
        if '=' in s:
            key, value = s.split('=')
            data[key] = value

print(data)
# {'BarC': '1.15', 'uptime': '31987895', 'nodeId': '99', 'sensorVal': '226'}
```

This can be reduced to this one-liner:

```
data = dict([s.split('=') for s in line.split() if 'BarC' in line and '=' in s])
print(data)
# {'BarC': '1.15', 'uptime': '31987895', 'nodeId': '99', 'sensorVal': '226'}
```

You can convert the values into the required data type using `float()` or `int()` as required:

```
>>> float(data['BarC'])
1.15
```